# how to let the fit function to define the fitting range?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I want to fit part of my data with python, using lmfit( it is not a must!). I'd like to have dynamic range of data to be fitted, meaning having two fitting parameters which define the part of my data to be fitted (let's call it lower and upper boundaries). 
the reason is I have many data sets. in each of the the fitting range varies and I cannot define a model to fit the whole range of data. on the other hand I cannot go through each data set and define the fitting range. 
is it possible at all? I thought of multiplying a pulse function to my model which affects the original data as well. though as far as I understand I cannot tell lmfit to multiply it to the data. so I am out of idea!

[image: orange line is the fit, blue dots are the fitted data, and the light green dots are the excluded data]

Comment: In order to somehow automate the data range selection, there must be some kind of criteria for filtering the data. Do you have some criteria to be used in this way?

Comment: not really. my idea is to use the fit. I can say where to start, it should be around the peak, though, how far it can go should depends on the chi square value which is coming out of the fit.

Answer (score 2):

The number of observations (data points or length of the residual array) returned by the model function or function to be minimized has to be the same throughout an individual fit.   Of course, this can change between successive fits.   So, you could try multiple fits for each data set with different ranges, perhaps set based on the previous fit.

I think that your idea of using "where the fit is bad" to determine where to not fit is somewhat suspect and you would want to make sure to avoid that leading to absurd results.   If for example, the range was automatically reduced so much so that Ndata = Nvariables+1, you could probably get a very low chi-square compared to Ndata = 100*Nvariables.

Without knowing the particulars, I think you would better off coming up with criteria for selecting the data range that depended on the data alone, and not a fit to it.